# standalone: varwidth option limits output width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, varwidth

It seems, that the `varwidth` option for the `standalone` class limits the output width. 
The problem is produced in the following example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,crop,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.3cm}
\path[draw=red] (0,0) -- (0,400pt) -- (400pt,400pt) -- (400pt,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.3cm}
\path[draw=red] (0,0) -- (0,200pt) -- (200pt,200pt) -- (200pt,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above code produces an image of 458x821pxl with the bigger square cut of on the right side:

[image]

Leaving away the `varwidth`option results in a 824x543px image with the two squares shown correctly:

[image]

I want to place several objects beneath each other, that's why I use the `varwidth`option in the first place. Unfortunatly my intended width of 510pt is to much for varwidth. So my question is: Is there a way to expand the limit set by `varwidth`? If not, is there another way to put objects beneath each other in `standalone` without using `varwidth`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `varwidth=<length>` option (length is optional and defaults to `\linewidth`) wraps the content into a `{varwidth}{<length>}` environment (from the `varwidth` package). This environment is like `{minipage}{<length>}` but will shrink horizontally to the content if it is smaller then `<length>`. This is the effect you see. This is not a bug.

The `varwidth` option is intended for content which requires paragraphs and therefore doesn't work in the restricted horizontal mode used otherwise by `standalone`. For `tikzpicture`s it is not required nor recommended.

A solution for your example would be to simply select a wider width. Using `varwidth=\maxdimen` or a similar high value should do it. (I didn't used `\maxdimen` as a default width because sometimes it caused errors if the resulting box was for some reason slightly wider than the content, resulting in a too large dimension value. Also, paragraphs which are `\maxdimen` wide look rather strange!)

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the [`standalone` manual](https://texdoc.org/pkg/standalone). It describes the `varwidth` option and all others in detail.

Comment: Thanks! As I stated earlier, I wanted to put several objects (not necessarily `tikzpicture`s) beneath each other and found an answer saying, this was possible by using the `varwidth`option since `standalone`would usually just ignore linebreaks. This is how I ran into the problem. Increasing the `\linewidth`wouldn't help either. But your solution works, thanks.

Comment: @Janek: Also the `preview` option instead of `crop` might work. It uses the `preview` package for cropping, which IIRC supports line breaks.

Comment: Thank you! My `standalone_verbatim.txt` that renders text file given by \txtfile parameter works thanks to your answer! Here is source code for reference for other readers: https://gist.github.com/gwpl/5128cb3cd348c38492da59800b6ab3f2

Comment: @MartinScharrer The link in your comment fails.

Comment: @skvery: Thanks, fixed now.